# Links do not open from click, only in new tab

Tags: menus, redirect, links, navigation

I'm fairly new to Wordpress, but I'm encountering a strange issue. I have a menu set up, and I've put links to some of my pages inside of it. But, when I try to click on any of the menu items, nothing happens. I can see the URL in the bottom left of my screen when I hover over the links, but when I click on them, I'm not redirected. The weird thing is that, when I open the links in a new tab (using either middle-mouse click or right click -> open in new tab), all of the links work. Does anyone have any idea what this might be? I'm completely lost.

Comment: I have the same problem. An answer would help me. Topic should be reopened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that some javascript is running on that page (in your theme) and preventing the default action of click event.

Disable all plugins you have and then theme to narrow down the cause. If disabling a plugin or reverting the theme fixes it, then you have found your culprit.

Also look for javascript errors in console. `Browser > Right click > Inspect Element > Console tab`

Comment: I thought I had disabled my plugins (because I read about this elsewhere too before I posted about it), but it was a network-wide one that I must have missed. Very helpful about the console, I didn't even think to use that for some reason. But it's all fixed now. Thank you!